# Replace the column value(%) and change its data type to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
RANK    DISTRIBUTORS    MARKET SHARE
 1       AB                17.02%
 2       NEO               17.00%
 3       EVE               14.3%
```

I have a dataframe with these 3 columns .I want to drop % from 'MARKET SHARE' column  and change data type to float.

```
df['MARKET SHARE'].replace('%','',inplace=True)
```

Desire result

```
RANK   DISTRIBUTORS  MARKET SHARE 
1       AB            17.02
2       NEO           17.00
3       EVE           14.3
```

Answer (score 3):

You are close, use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) with casting to float:

```
df['MARKET SHARE'] = df['MARKET SHARE'].str.replace('%','').astype(float)
```

Or:

```
df['MARKET SHARE'] = df['MARKET SHARE'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
```

Comment: or even `.str[:-1]`

Comment: @timgeb - thinking about it, but if some value has no `%` ? then number is removed.

Comment: garbage in garbage out :)